# How many Salesforce users do we need to install MC Connect / SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

When installing MC Connect, is it a best practice to have 2 Salesforce Admin users ? 
One for installing the MC Connector, and the other to use as Salesforce system tracking user (to connect with a SFMC API user)?
Or does just one Salesforce Admin user is enough ?

Comment: Depends on how many BUs you have and whether it's a multi-org setup or a single-org. In single-org, one API user for each cloud is enough, so you log in as yourself and create a user with all required permissions. For multi-org, it all depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I will always recommend using a separate user for the integration (tracking user) which is not also used for regular admin work. This is due to potential issues with the connector breaking in cases someone becomes locked out, or changes password - which might cause the integration to break. Forcing you, in best case, to clear out oauth token - as descirbed by [zuzannamj](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50456/zuzannamj) in [this great post](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/07/31/troubleshooting-marketing-cloud-connect/).